# selectedElement does not display angular 1 services angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I am currently going though the **angularjs 1** services tutorial on you tube and I am stuck at the following point.

[youtube link](https://youtu.be/wYP0xCjzrNA?t=10m22s)

I am trying to get the **selectedElement** to display in my index.html file

The value displays when using the following code:

```
{{ sensormeasurements[0].sensorMeasurementID }}
```

however any of combination below does not.

```
{{ selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID }}
{{ sensormeasurements.selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID }}
{{ fishHouseMonitorController.selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID }}
{{ $scope.selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID }}
```

Any idea on the proper syntax to get the selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID to show up on my HTML page?

Thanks for your help on this.
Steve

I have the following code in my **app3.js** file

```
var app = angular.module('fishHouseMonitorApp', []);

app.controller('fishHouseMonitorController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.eastcentralmdaa.org/fishhousemonitor/api/v1/sensormeasurements")
    .then(function(response) { 
        $scope.sensormeasurements = response.data; });
        // do some error checking to ensure there is an element 0?
        $scope.selectedElement = $scope.sensormeasurements[0];
    }
);
```

I have the following code in my **index.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="app2.js">app3.js</script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container" ng-app="fishHouseMonitorApp" ng-controller="fishHouseMonitorController">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="sensormeasurement in sensormeasurements" ng-click="selectContact($index)">
                            <span>{{ sensormeasurement.sensorMeasurementDateTime }}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <img src="../img/sensor.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <!-- <h4 class="media-heading">{{ sensormeasurements[0].sensorMeasurementID }}</h4> -->
                            <h4 class="media-heading">{{ selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID }}</h4> 
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <h4>sensorMeasurementID</h4>
                                <p>
                                    {{ selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID }}
                                    {{ sensormeasurements.selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID }}
                                    {{ fishHouseMonitorController.selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID }}
                                    {{ $scope.selectedElement.sensorMeasurementID }}
                                    {{ sensormeasurements[0].sensorMeasurementID }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <h4>userSystemSensorID</h4>
                                <p>
                                    {{ sensormeasurements[0].userSystemSensorID }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <h4>sensorMeasurementDateTime</h4>
                                <p>
                                    {{ sensormeasurements[0].sensorMeasurementDateTime }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    <h4>sensorMeasurementValue</h4>
                                <p>
                                    {{ sensormeasurements[0].sensorMeasurementValue }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Create a demo in plunker that reproduces problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error.

```
<script src="app2.js">app3.js</script>
```

I was modifying the wrong file...